# WiFi does not work if booting Raspberry Pi from SSD on USB

Tags: wifi, usb

The WiFi does not work on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ if I boot the RPi from an SSD disk connected to one of the USB ports (Raspbian Stretch). Clicking on the "double arrow" icon at the top right of the screen shows "No wireless interfaces found". For troubleshooting, I flashed the same image I used for the SSD to an SD card and booted the RPi from the SD card. The WiFi works as expected with the SD card.

What is going on? How can I make the WiFi work with the SSD?

Comment: Please boot from the SSD disk. Then edit your question an paste the output of this commands into it: `sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (obscure the password)  and `ip addr show`.

Comment: I just realised that I also sometimes run into problems with the WiFi if running from the SD card, and sometimes the WiFi works from the SSD. My initial "observation" that the problem happens only with the SSD was probably just a coincidence.